# How to filter after parsing CSV values contained in Google Sheets cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex, concatenate

I would like to be able to match all cells in column A (titles) that have one of the comma-separated values in column E (Key Search Terms). This will involve at least two steps. 1) Parse each of the respective key search term cells into and array of trimmed text values (eg cell E10 would be ["stuff", "food fluff", "green"]. 2) Regex match the exact pattern contained under the tags column (column F).

The desired result in the second image depicted below will be a filter that only allows the article title "Hating on Food: A Viable Source of Catharsis?" to get through. Note that "Being Cool: A Guide" did NOT make the cut because although it contains the word "food" in its corresponding key search terms cell it is in the context of "food fluff" which is a distinct value from "food" in isolation.

I could puzzle over this for a while but I have a client that needs a quick solution and I'm having trouble seeing how to realize this result. I think I have completed part step one with the following formula: `ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(E10, ",")))` This shows the parsing of a single cell into an array from its CSV value-- in this case "stuff", "food fluff", "green".

PS [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10074MnE8m-AGIu-EheIkhSk00375WgjAnHiQXFoDYnQ/edit?usp=sharing) is a link to the sheet in question

[image: Tags to Parse]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `F10` for the tenth row :

```
=textjoin(",",false,ArrayFormula(iferror(REGEXEXTRACT(A10,TRANSPOSE(ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(E10, ","))))))))
```

Basically `REGEXTRACT()` accept arrays.

Comment: This merely yields ',,' in the cell I paste it into. I've added a link to the sheet in my original question if you want to fiddle with it.

Comment: I just edited your sheet : is this your expected result ? I have to be honest : _"Note that "Being Cool: A Guide" did NOT make the cut because although it contains the word "food" in its corresponding key search terms cell it is in the context of "food fluff" which is a distinct value from "food" in isolation."_  I don't understand at all where you find "food" in the string "Being Cool: a Guide". Maybe try to give a before/after screenshot so we can have a better understanding of your needs.

Comment: "Food" is not contained in "Being Cool: a Guide." It is contained (as a substring) in the key search terms column associated with the row containing "Being Cool: a Guide." ["stuff","food fluff", "green"]. But we don't want sub-strings to count as a match. Only case insensitive and trimmed exact matches of the csv values. Hence "Hating on Food: A Viable Basis of Catharsis" made the cut (because its csv array is ["stuff","food","green"])-- an exact match (ie "food") is found. Also, I included a second screen shot that shows this result in a separate sheet

Answer (score 0):

### true ArrayFormula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IFERROR(IF(REGEXMATCH(LOWER(A5:A10), 
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(E5:E10, ", ", "♦"), "♦")), 
 SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(E5:E10, ", ", "♦"), "♦"), ))),,999^99))), " ", ", "))
```

[image: 0]